# Flutter Firestore: Check if doc exists

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored some data in firestore like this(Image attached):
Crud->notes(collection)->1234(userId)(doc)->items(collection)->....notes data

I am using this function to check if userId exists, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

```
static Future checkDocumentExists(input) async {
  var userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes').doc(input);
  var doc = await userDocRef.get();
  if (!doc.exists) {
    debugPrint('No such document exists!');
  } else {
    debugPrint('Document data:' + doc.data().toString());
  }
}
```

[image: Firestore structure]

Comment: "it doesn't work" is really hard to help with. When you step through this code line by line in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The code runs without any error. As the name of the function suggests, it should print the document if it exists. The code I wrote should display, *The document exists* but the condition never become true.

Comment: Good to hear there are no errors. That's not what I asked though. Stepping through your code in a debugger is a key step in troubleshooting problems. --- Does either of your `debugPrint` statements show up in the output?